# How to get latest records for by records type in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

My table looks like:

```
ID     NAME      TYPE      INSERTION_DATE      OCCURRANCE_DATE

I100   ABC       WEEKLY    2019-12-31          2019-12-30
I100   ABC       WEEKLY    2019-12-22          2019-12-20
I101   DEF       MONTHLY   2019-12-31          2019-12-30
I101   DEF       MONTHLY   2019-12-01          2019-11-29
```

How I can get latest records based on `OCCURANCE_DATE` for each type (Weekly & monthly) using SQL query. The result should be like this:

```
ID     NAME      TYPE      INSERTION_DATE      OCCURRANCE_DATE

I100   ABC       WEEKLY    2019-12-31          2019-12-30
I101   DEF       MONTHLY   2019-12-31          2019-12-30
```

Comment: Specify MySQL version.

Comment: While 'minimal', this data set isn't sufficiently 'complete' to provide a definitive answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options to address this greatest-n-per-group question.

You can filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.occurence_date = (
    select max(t1.occurence_date)
    from mytable t1
    where t1.type = t.type
)
```

Another typical solution is the anti-`left join`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
left join mytable t1 on t1.type = t.type and t1.occurence_date > t.occurence_date
where t1.id is null
```

Comment: Note: Your second query is certainly not an antipattern.  In software, "antipattern" means the opposite of good design, which isn't the case with your answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen But it is an 'antepattern' - as in 'the way we did it before'

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I call *left join antipattern* this technique with `left join ... t1 where t1 is null`. But probably this is not the correct designation!

Comment: @GMB I think it's called an _antijoin_, not an antipattern.

Answer (score 1):

A correlated subquery is a simple method:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.OCCURANCE_DATE = (select max(t2.OCCURANCE_DATE)
                          from t t2
                          where t2.type = t.type
                         );
```